# Existing SQL Server instance. Cannot log in

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 instance installed on a windows XP host. Had a situation where my Windows 2008 server had a critical hardware failure and I reached a point where that OS had to be completely reinstalled.

Anyway, whenever I attempt to log into SSMS to the default instance through windows authentication it tells me that the log in failed, error 18456.

Attempted to run the program as administrator, no dice. I cannot log in with SQL Server authentication, either.

I would really hate to delete the instance and re-create it. Anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there should be an entry after or prior to the error you provided in the SQL Error logs that gives you the details about why the login failed. If you can provide that entry of the error log we can provide you a little bit more assistance.